# How to show the uniqueness of the solution of the time dependent linear system in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: dynamical-systems

Consider the time dependent linear system in $\mathbb{R}^n$:

$$
\dot{x} = Ax + b(t),
$$
where $b: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous.
Prove that

$$
x(t) = e^{At}x_0 + \int_0^t e^{A(t-s)}b(s)d(s), \tag{1}
$$
for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is the unique solution satisfying the initial condition $x(0) = x_0$.

My try: 
I tried to take the derivative with respect to Leibniz rule to show that $(1)$ satisfies the systems of differential equation.

$$
\dot{x}(t) = Ae^{At}x_0 +\frac{ \mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\bigg(\int_0^t e^{A(t-s)}b(s)d(s)\bigg)
$$

Also, I have no idea how to prove uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

If there were two solutions with the same $x_0$, then their difference $h$ would satisfy $$\dot{h}=Ah,\quad h(0)=0,$$ equivalent to $$h(t)=\int_0^tAh$$

Since this is reminiscent of Banach's theorem, let $Ty(t):=\int_0^tAy$. Then $$\|T(u-v)\|=\sup_t|\int_0^t A(u-v)| \le \|A\|\|u-v\|\int_0^t1\le\|A\||t|\|u-v\|$$ where $\|u\|$ is the sup-norm. So for $t$ small enough, the mapping $T$ is a contraction mapping and has a unique fixed point. In fact, clearly, this is zero, i.e. $h=0$.

Comment: What is the integral with respect to?

Comment: The variable $t$.